# Creating more than one segue use CollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode

As shown at the image below, I have a CollectionViewCell and would like to create more than one segue to the TableViewController and ViewController.

How can I create more than one segue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create more than one segue to the TableViewController and ViewController, you need to create a segues from the view controller which holds the collection view (not cell) to the destinations view controllers, for example:

```
UICollectionViewController -> UIViewController1
UICollectionViewController -> UIViewController2
//...etc
```

Remember to add identifier to each segues.

And in the code override `UICollectionViewDelegate` method

```
collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

inside that method check which cell was tapped (indexPath) and if it was cell1 call segue with the right identifier:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("goToVC1Identifier", sender: nil)
```

Comment: For some reason I got mixed up with whatever I have in my mind. Anyway, what I did was to connect it from the collectionviewcontroller to my tableviewcontroller and viewcontroller and perform segue. That does the job